# How to get ${kubernetes.namespace_name} for index_name in fluentd?

Tags: fluentd

Did anyone manage to get kubernetes.namespace_name as indexName? I tried this and its not working.

```
index_name ${kubernetes.namespace_name}.%Y%m%d
```

Comment: Have you tried `${record['kubernetes']['namespace_name']}`? Also make sure the key exists in the record. More information [here](https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch#dynamic-configuration).

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below mentioned steps for complete installation. I have Added below **fluentd.conf** configmap file with below line.

`logstash_prefix clustername-${record['kubernetes']['namespace_name']}`

**Fluentd-DaemonSet**

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logging
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logging
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: fluentd                           
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-elasticsearch 
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "elasticsearch"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER
            value: "user"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
            value: "password"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NAME
            value: "clustername"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 500Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-fluentd
          mountPath: /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf
          subPath: fluent.conf
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: config-fluentd
        configMap:
          name: fluentd-conf                      
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

**Add fluentd.conf file**

```
kubectl create cm config-fluentd --from-file fluentd.conf
```

```html
<match fluent.**>
    # this tells fluentd to not output its log on stdout
    @type null
</match>

# Fetch all container logs
<source>
  @id kubernetes-containers.log
  @type tail
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/kubernetes-containers.log.pos
  tag raw.kubernetes.*
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type multi_format
    <pattern>
      format json
      time_key time
      time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
    </pattern>
    <pattern>
      format /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) [^ ]* (?<log>.*)$/
      time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%:z
    </pattern>
  </parse>
</source>

# Detect exceptions in the log output and forward them as one log entry.
<match raw.kubernetes.**>
  @id raw.kubernetes
  @type detect_exceptions
  remove_tag_prefix raw
  message log
  stream stream
  multiline_flush_interval 5
  max_bytes 500000
  max_lines 1000
</match>

# Concatenate multi-line logs
<filter **>
  @id filter_concat
  @type concat
  key message
  multiline_end_regexp /\n$/
  separator ""
</filter>

# Add records with Kubernetes metadata
<filter kubernetes.**>
  @id filter_kubernetes_metadata
  @type kubernetes_metadata
</filter>

# Fixes json fields for Elasticsearch
<filter kubernetes.**>
  @id filter_parser
  @type parser
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type multi_format
    <pattern>
      format json
    </pattern>
    <pattern>
      format none
    </pattern>
  </parse>
</filter>
<match **>
   @type elasticsearch_dynamic
   @id out_es
   @log_level info
     
   include_tag_key true
   host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
   port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
   path "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PATH']}"
   scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'http'}"
   ssl_verify "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY'] || 'true'}"
   user "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER']}"
   password "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD']}"
   reload_connections "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_CONNECTIONS'] || 'true'}"
   logstash_prefix clustername-${record['kubernetes']['namespace_name']}
   logstash_format true
   type_name fluentd
   buffer_chunk_limit "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_CHUNK_LIMIT_SIZE'] || '2M'}"
   buffer_queue_limit "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_QUEUE_LIMIT_LENGTH'] || '32'}"
   flush_interval "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_FLUSH_INTERVAL'] || '5s'}"
   max_retry_wait "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_RETRY_MAX_INTERVAL'] || '30'}"
   disable_retry_limit
   num_threads "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_FLUSH_THREAD_COUNT'] || '8'}"
</match>
```

**Official Repo:**
     https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset

If you want to divide fluentd.conf file to other files then you can use below annotation
in fluentd.conf and add as a configmap and volume in DaemonSet.

Annotation

```
@include systemd.conf
@include kubernetes.conf
```

Configmap for above files

Add configmap similar to fluentd-config as a configmap for seperated config files.

Comment: where does the record come from?  ${record['kubernetes']['namespace_name']}

Comment: Hi, I have modified fluentd.conf file with kuberenetes metadata. Using  below lines you will be able to enable the kubernetes metadata and then you will use record(Ruby command) for fetching the data.                                                       
   <filter kubernetes.**>
If you don't have record plugin installed you can add plugin in Gemfile using command "gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch', '4.0.7' " and then create new image and  you will have that or better if you can use the one image which I mentioned as that is  the latest stable image.

Answer (score 2):

Well, mine here I did by label, I had to add a label on the objects (deployment, statefulset and etc ...) called **fluentd: "true"**

Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: your-name-space
  labels:
    app: kafka
    version: "2.6.0"
    component: queues
    part-of: appsbots
    managed-by: kubectl
    fluentd: "true"
```

In the fluent.conf file, I made a configmap for the fluentd Daemonset as shown below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
    version: v1
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
data:
  fluent.conf: |-
    <match fluent.**>
        # this tells fluentd to not output its log on stdout
        @type null
    </match>

    # here we read the logs from Docker's containers and parse them
    <source>
      @type tail
      path /var/log/containers/*.log
      pos_file /var/log/containers.log.pos
      tag kubernetes.*
      read_from_head true
      <parse>
        @type json
        time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
      </parse>
      <pattern>
        format /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout) [^ ]* (?<log>.*)$/
        time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%:z
      </pattern>
    </source>

    # Kubernetes metadata
    <filter kubernetes.**>
        @type kubernetes_metadata
    </filter>

    <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**kube-system**.log>
      @type null
    </match>

    # <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**kube-logging**.log>
    # @type null
    # </match>

    <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**_istio-proxy_**>
      @type null
    </match>
    

    <filter kubernetes.**>
      @type grep
      <regexp>
        key $["kubernetes"]["labels"]["fluentd"]        
        pattern true
      </regexp>
    </filter>


    <filter kubernetes.**>
      @type grep
      <exclude>
        key $["kubernetes"]["labels"]["fluentd"]        
        pattern false
      </exclude>
    </filter>
    


    #Just an example of what kind of variables can come inside. This part does not apply as config. Do your config with ENV vars
    <match **>
      @type elasticsearch
      @id out_es
      @log_level info
      include_tag_key true
      host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
      port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
      scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'http'}"
      ssl_verify "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY'] || 'true'}"
      user "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER']}"
      password "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD']}"
      reload_connections "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_CONNECTIONS'] || 'true'}"
      logstash_prefix "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_PREFIX'] || 'logstash'}"
      logstash_format true
      buffer_chunk_limit "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_CHUNK_LIMIT_SIZE'] || '2M'}"
      buffer_queue_limit "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_QUEUE_LIMIT_LENGTH'] || '32'}"
      flush_interval "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_FLUSH_INTERVAL'] || '5s'}"
      max_retry_wait "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_RETRY_MAX_INTERVAL'] || '30'}"
      disable_retry_limit num_threads "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_FLUSH_THREAD_COUNT'] || '8'}"
      <buffer>
           @type file
           path /var/log/fluentd-buffers/kubernetes.system.buffer
           flush_mode interval
           retry_type exponential_backoff
           flush_thread_count 2
           flush_interval 5s
           retry_forever true
           retry_max_interval 30
           chunk_limit_size 2M
           queue_limit_length 32
           overflow_action block
       </buffer>
    </match>
```

And now the fluentd Deamon file. The image I am using is reference to version v1.10. however it can be the same saw.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
    version: v1
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
  annotations:
    configmap.reloader.stakater.com/reload: "fluentd-config"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logging
        version: v1
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: didevlab/mutpoc:fluentd #base--> fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.10-debian-elasticsearch7-1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "elasticsearch-svc.{{ name_corp }}-{{ app_enviroment }}"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
          - name: FLUENT_UID
            value: "0"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:        
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
        - name: config-fluentd
          mountPath: /fluentd/etc
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:      
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: config-fluentd
        configMap:
          name: fluentd-config
```

\o/Good is that, by boyBR